# The requested URL /pay was not found on this serve r laravel project , Cpanel, bluehost,404 not found

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel, bluehost

the home page on my website is working correctly but the links inside the website don't work 
when I click on the button that has a link the "The requested URL /pay was not found on this server" error appears.
 my public folder in the project folder has a .htaccess file
(myproject/public/.htaccess)
 and it contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm new in hosting
please any help.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in your `.htaccess` after `RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteBase /`

So your `.htaccess` should look like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```